# Newbie Question on Permissions

Tags: debian, permissions, users, group

I am really new to Linux and having just brought a Raspberry Pi I decided to run a simple apache server.
I found a simple tutorial on how to install and setup the apache server which is what I have done.
Part of the tutorial said to do

```
sudo usermod -a -G www-data pi
sudo chown -R -f www-data:www-data /var/www
```

This is supposed to give the user `pi` ownership and access to `/var/www`

I went to create a directory `/var/www/dump` but it would not let me saying `permission denied`.

So I `cd`ed to the `/var` directory and `ls -l` shows

```
pi@server:/var $ ls -l
drwxr-xr-x  4 www-data www-data      4096 Nov  7 18:56 www
```

if I do a `ls -l` in the `www` directory it shows

```
pi@server:/var/www $ ls -l
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data 4096 Nov  7 13:51 html
```

So according to this I should as user `pi` be able to create a directory and files however I can not.

After reboot, the groups command shows user Pi is a member of `pi adm dialout cdrom sudo audio www-data video plugdev games users input netdev gpio i2c sp`, but if I try `nano testfile.php` and then try to write out I get `[ Error writing tmpfile.php: Permission denied ]`.

Comment: You have to [reboot or  logout and login after adding a user to a group](https://askubuntu.com/a/69259/955298). The command `groups` shows in which groups the current user is

Comment: Thank you. I have reboot but still can not get to create a file without resorting to using sudo. For example the groups command shows user Pi is a member of "pi adm dialout cdrom sudo audio www-data video plugdev games users input netdev gpio i2c spi" but if I try nano testfile.php and then try to write out I get [ Error writing tmpfile.php: Permission denied ]. So Pi is a memebr of www-data and the directory is owned by www-data. I must be going wrong somewhere

Comment: see https://ibb.co/zNDnMDM for a screen image

Comment: Please post images as part of question, and post text as text (not images of text).

Answer (score 3):

## Groups

The command `sudo usermod -a -G www-data pi` only writes to a config file.
At login, this file is read. Existing processes are not affected.

The easiest way to gain join a new group is to logout and back in again (a reboot will log you out).

---

The `newgrp` command is another, but it only affects its own child processes.

## Mode

The other part of the permission is in the mode.
Your directory has a mode of `drwxr-xr-x`

- The first char `d` says that it is a directory.
- The next 3 chars are for the owning user, it has `r`ead, `w`rite (and delete), and `x` cross (e`x`ecute for files).
- The next 3. The group has `r`ead, and `x` cross, but no `w`rite
- The last 3. Other, has the same as group (don't add write to it).

You need to add `w`rite permission to the directories group:

`chmod -R g+w /var/www` (This will work on Gnu `chmod` and I am told many others).

Comment: Thank you so much crtl-alt-delor, that chmod command fixed it though I did have to run it with the sudo prefix.

Comment: Yes. You will need `sudo` as your user is not the owner. So you need elevated privileges.